# Implementing a TLV protocol via TCP

Tags: c++, python, tcp, protocol-buffers

I'm currently trying to implement a (T)LV protocol to be used on top of TCP. A very early version of this protocol was built by just sending one message per send-recv pair. (i.e. send("message to transmit" -- recv(... )). This is really bad bandwidth-wise - I guess because I'm sending really small packets.
So now I am trying to switch to a LV protocol, sending several messages at once only seperated by their respective length (I am now using Protocol Buffers to serialize my data).

I now have two questions:

- In python I send by doing

  `sock.send(struct.pack("<H", len(gtMessage.SerializeToString())))
  sock.send(gtMessage.SerializeToString())`

If I now put this into a loop and sent several of those messages I'd end up with my old problem, as far as I understand. Can I somehow string the string to be sent together?

- In C++ I receive receive first the length of the message and then read the number of bytes indicated by the length field.

Is it better performance-wise to first read everything from TCP and then parse it, or can I read one message, then parse it and only then read the next bit from the wire?

**Edit:**  So after doing some more research I'd rephrase the first question as:

Is

```
    sock.send("somestring")
    sock.send("somestring")
```

the same as

```
sock.send("somestring"+"somestring")
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing two sends in a row may result in two actual packets going out, which is not so great.  To fix this you can concatenate the two pieces yourself, or use [`writev`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-writev) (aka "gather write"), or [TCP_CORK](http://www.baus.net/on-tcp_cork) on the first send to prevent it from turning into a packet all by itself.

As for the receive side, you should receive a big block (as much as you can up to some reasonable limit, say a couple megabytes or something), and then parse it.  Do not try to receive just one or two bytes for the size then do another receive after that--this is inefficient and you may still end up with "short reads" if the sent message was fragmented.